# Showing a ring homomorphism is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

Suppose that $ϕ : R \to S$ is a ring isomorphism. As $ϕ$ is a bijection, it has an inverse map $ψ : S \to R$
such that $ψ \circ ϕ : R \to R$ is the identity map on $R$ and $ϕ \circ ψ : S \to S$ is the identity map on $S$. Prove that
$ψ : S \to R$ is a ring homomorphism.

I've proved this one way, but I need to prove that it is an isomorphism given that it's a ring homomorphism.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused about what you have to prove. The question as defined in your first paragraph only has "one way": you just have to prove that $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism given that it is the inverse of a (bijective) ring homomorphism.

Comment: What do you want to prove? Do you want to prove $\psi$ is a ring homomorphism? What is the one way you have proved?

Comment: Okay sorry bad wording. It's an iff. On mobile so can't do the symbols. A map is an isomorphism iff there exists an inverse homomorphic map such that the 2 maps composed is the identity map. I have proved left to right just struggling with right to left

Answer (score 0):

The ring homomorphism $\psi$ is a ring isomorphism since it is a bijection. You know that because you know that $\psi^{-1}=\phi$.

Comment: I think the point is to prove that the inverse of an isomorphism is not just a map of sets, but a homomorphism.

Comment: @DavidHill Why do you think that? The OP wrote “ given that it's a ring homomorphism”.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't read that. Then this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @DavidHill Probably it doesn't.