# Proof that a ring homomorphism is isomorphic if and only if there is another ring homomorphism such that there is an identity map on R and S

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring homomorphism $\phi:R \to S$ is an isomorphism if and only if there exists another ring homomorphism $\psi:S \to R$ such that $\psi\circ\phi:R\to R$ is the identity map on R and $\phi\circ\psi:S \to S$ is the identity map on S.

I'm struggling to find a proof to help my understanding, thank you.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652194/showing-a-ring-homomorphism-is-an-isomorphism?rq=1

Comment: In category theory, this is actually the _definition_ of an isomorphism.

Comment: The fact that these are ring homomorphisms is irrelevant.  You need to prove that a function is bijective if and only if it is invertible.

Comment: @Jonathan: The type of structure we're considering *is* relevant. For example, a morphism of topological spaces (i.e. a continuous function) can be an isomorphism of sets without being an isomorphism of topological spaces. For example, $x \mapsto \exp(2 \pi i x)$ as a map from $[0,1)$ to the unit circle in the complex plane. Or the identity map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where the domain has the discrete topology and the codomain has the usual topology.

Comment: @Hurkyl In the category of rings, the (category of functions) inverse of bijectiive isomorphism is again a (iso)morphism.  I agree that this is not true in the category of topological spaces.

Answer (score 1):

$\impliedby$

$\phi$ is injective because it has kernel zero: if $x\in \ker(\phi)$, then $\phi(x)=0$ implies $x=\psi\phi(x)=0$

$\phi$ is surjective because, given $y\in S$, $\phi\psi(y)=y$, so $\psi(y)\in R$ maps to $y$.

$\implies$

In the other direction, you just check that $\phi^{-1}=\psi$.

Comment: Does not it have to be mentioned that the rings are unitary in this question?

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 at what juncture would that matter?

Comment: Instead of using the kernal to show injectivity can you say letting $x$ and $x’$ be in S. If $\phi(\psi(x)) = \phi(\psi(x’))$ then it follows that $x=x’$ or would there be more to it?

Comment: @miscellaneous Same thing, sure.

Comment: Great thank you, just wanted to make sure it was that way round rather than $x$ and $x’$ in R with $\psi(\phi(x))=\psi(\phi(x’))$ showing $x=x’$

Comment: @rschwieb  The statement kernel is  zero imply that $1_S\in S$.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 if $S$ hasidentity, then of course it is in $S$. If you mean $S$ necessarily has identity, then that will be true iff $R$ has an identity. Either way, it seems totally irrelevant to this question. The identities may or may not exist: the problem is still true.

Comment: @rschwieb. Ok Thank you. I need your last comment.